# Django: Warning: Incorrect integer value: 'UnlocksBranch' for column 'type_id' at row 1

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django app that pulls data from a Bugzilla database and I am having trouble getting the flags.

```
class Bugzilla_bugs(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'bugs'

    bug_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

The flagtypes table which describes all of the different flag names and what they mean.

```
class Bugzilla_flagtypes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'flagtypes'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    ...
```

The flags table, which is a one-to-many mapping of bug_id, type_id and status values for each bug.

```
class Bugzilla_flags(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'flags'

    type_id = models.ForeignKey(Bugzilla_flagtypes,related_name='flagtype',db_column='type_id',to_field='name')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bug_id = models.ForeignKey(Bugzilla_bugs,related_name='flaglines',db_column='bug_id',to_field='bug_id')
```

When I try to get the flaglines for a particular bug:

```
bug = Bugzilla_bugs.objects.using('bugzilla').get(bug_id=12345)
bug.flaglines.get(type_id="UnlocksBranch")
```

I get the exception:

```
>>> bug.flaglines.get(type_id__name="UnlocksBranch")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 351, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 122, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 128, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 176, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
Warning: Incorrect integer value: 'UnlocksBranch' for column 'type_id' at row 1
```

I am trying to use the 'get' method to get the value of the 'status' field in the flags table.

If I try to use flaglines to get query the numerical type_id, I get DoesNotExist.

```
>>> bug.flaglines.get(type_id=20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "/home/shubbard/django/cpe/dev/cpe/bugzilla/models.py", line 160, in __unicode__
    return unicode(self.type_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 572, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 357, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Bugzilla_flagtypes matching query does not exist.
```

I know that the bug has that flag set.

```
mysql> select * from flags where bug_id=12345;
+-------+---------+--------+--------+
| id    | type_id | status | bug_id |
+-------+---------+--------+--------+
| 71732 |      29 | +      |  12345 |
| 72538 |      41 | +      |  12345 |
| 72547 |      12 | +      |  12345 |
| 72548 |      31 | ?      |  12345 |
| 72549 |      33 | ?      |  12345 |
| 72550 |      20 | ?      |  12345 |
| 72551 |      36 | ?      |  12345 |
+-------+---------+--------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: exactly thast, your `bug_id` is supposed to be an integer, that is a whole number. `UnlocksBranch` is not a number except maybe in Base-36 number system.

Comment: The bug_id is a whole number, 12345.  If I look at the row in the database the bug_id field is 12345, the type_id is 20, and the status is "?".  In the flagtypes table, the row ID 20, has the name "UnlocksBranch".  What I want to get, is the status of "?".

Comment: `bug.flaglines.get(type_id="UnlocksBranch")` <-- you need to use the flagtype id here (i.e. `20`), not the flagtype name

Comment: If I search for the number of the type_id, I get: DoesNotExist: Bugzilla_flagtypes matching query does not exist.  I know that the row does exist, and there is a line in the flags table with the matching bug_id and type_id in the same row.

Comment: you'd need to use the type_id (which you say is `20`) not the bug_id `12345`

Comment: Edited the post again with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see now, I think the problem is your flags model is defined with:

```
type_id = models.ForeignKey(Bugzilla_flagtypes,related_name='flagtype',db_column='type_id',to_field='name')`
```

...but in the db the `type_id` column in the `flags` table clearly contains the integer `id` of the flagtype... in other words your model definition doesn't match the db schema, you need to remove the `to_field` from the ForeignKey above.

Then this should work:

```
bug.flaglines.get(type_id__name="UnlocksBranch")
```

Comment: It is 100% the exact same error.  The entire error stack is the same.  I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the options in the FK references.

Comment: paste the entire error stack because it must be coming from somewhere other than this line of code

Comment: Edited the original post with the full stack.